# Does the Injustice Storyline continue into the Batman Beyond Future?

Tags: dc, batman-beyond, injustice

DC's *Injustice* is an alternate timeline based on a video game, but it has spun into its own continuity. Depending on what character ends the game, outcomes will differ.

However, has there been any indication the *Injustice* story continues into the *Batman Beyond* time frame?

Comment: They're unrelated. Although it isn't referenced directly, certain instances can be referred to to say that they aren't related

Comment: So you're basically asking if there is a Injustice version of Terry McGinnis?